# UIRefreshControl crashes while refreshing Tableview Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, asynchronous, uirefreshcontrol

I can't refresh my **TVC. It crashes when I drag down to refresh.** The icon is there, but then it quits. I'm sure its something simple. There are similar questions out there which have not been considered.

Taken from my viewDidLoad method body:

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(refreshInvoked:forState:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];

refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title
                                                            attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.0]}];
[self refreshFeed];
```

Which refers to:

```
-(void)refreshFeed 
{
   RSSLoader* rss = [[RSSLoader alloc] init];    
   [rss fetchRssWithURL:feedURL
            complete:^(NSString *title, NSArray *results) {
                dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader",NULL);
                dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
                _objects = results;
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                //completed fetching the RSS
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //               [(HeaderView*)self.tableView.tableHeaderView setText:title];
                    // [(ArticleItem*)self.tableView.]
                });
                });
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please include the crash log when asking about crashes, ACB is probably right but why make us guess?

Comment: @jrturton, That is true. My answer is purely based on an assumption and could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your action method to:

```
[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(refreshFeed)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Looks like you were pointing to `refreshInvoked:forState:` which was not present in self.

Comment: You can also try to implement `- (void)refreshInvoked:(id)sender forState:(UIEvent *)event` and keep the addTarget part as it is.

Comment: The answer body's solution instantly solved the problem. Now the question of dismissing the refreshControl after its finished.

Comment: Glad to know that. _"Now the question of dismissing the refreshControl after its finished."_ - You dont have to dismiss it. I will automatically go back to previous state.

Answer (score 4):

**UIRefreshControl is not meant to be added as subview**... doing so will get you some trouble and you need to unregister its target on VC dealloc... else you might get some issues, when the UIRefreshControl calls your dead VC (as it doesn't keep a weak or strong reference to your VC)